# How to enable server in hotspot?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, linux, wifi-hotspot, command-line

I got the error while trying this on command line interface

> root@sabresd_6dq:/ # hostapd_cli wps_pbc
>   Failed to connect to hostapd - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an unlocked bootloader and the latest TWRP recovery (I confirmed this works perfectly on the US Nexus 6 on Verizon).

1. Boot into recovery, go to `advanced`, and click `mount` and select `system`.
2. Connect your phone to your computer. Open `terminal/cmd` and run the following:

> adb pull /system/build.prop

This will pull the build.prop onto your computer in the location where your terminal is open.
Edit that in your text editor on your computer and then add the following line:

> net.tethering.noprovisioning=true

`Save`, and then run

> adb push build.prop /system/

This puts it back on your phone, but the permissions might be funky, so run

> adb shell
>
> chmod 644 /system/build.prop
>
> exit

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus6/comments/3npkzz/on_marshmallow_you_can_have_ad_blocking_and/)

Comment: try this method if it doesn't work means inform me! i will give you an another solution

Comment: what do yo you mean by the first line : `I got it working without having to root my phone, but I did have to put TWRP on for it to work.`

Comment: Not only the file's permissions, but also the ownership might be messed up. Better to run `chown 0.0 /system/build.prop` either before or after `chmod`.